# Received an error message when installing Beautiful Soup4 on Mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal, beautifulsoup, access-denied

I am using a Mac and I get an error message on my terminal when I try to install Beautiful Soup. I have Python 3 installed already.

This is what I did after unpacking the Beautiful Soup zip file

```
$ cd Users/thepredestrian/Desktop/beautifulsoup4-4.4.1

$ python setup.py install
```

This is the error message that appears:

> Checking .pth file support in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
>   error: can't create or remove files in install directory
>
> The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in
>   the installation directory:
>
> ```
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-966.pth'
> ```
>
> The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix,
>   or the distutils default setting) was:
>
> ```
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
> ```

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: did you try with sudo?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing with sudo.

> sudo python setup.py install

An alternate way is to use virtual environment. Inside a virtual environment, you can install dependencies locally rather than system wide, so you won't need access to a root account.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv test
cd test
source bin/activate
```

The first line installs virtualenv. The second line creates a virtual environment. The third and fourth line activates (starts) the virtualenv. You will notice the change in prompt. Inside virtualenv, you can install dependencies (e.g BeautifulSoup), run python scripts and so on. Once you're done, you can deactivate the environment by simply typing *deactivate* in the shell.